# Unrecognized binary file

Tags: files

I have this unrecognized file which is scary. It was not there before and I don't know whether it's a virus or something else. When I checked its properties it shows the size as `101.2 GB (1,01,23,37,21,344 bytes)` and type as `Binary (application/octet-stream)`. When I try to open the file it shows "could not display"!

What is it and how do I open it?!

My home folder:
[image]

Properties window:
[image]

Comment: It maybe a truecrypt encrypted container.

Comment: Don't change the NAME!!!  It may be a key, for the file try to open it

Comment: Humm, I would thanks it would be a true-crypt encrypted container. Or some sort. My second guess would be it is a temporary file, or a root-kit trying to get your information and put it in the file so it can be sent back to the host. Check your firewall to make sure it is not malware also. YES LINUX CAN GET MALWARE TOO, BUT IT IS VERY UNCOMMON.

Answer (score 1):

I damn sure it is an **truecrypt encrypted conatiner file**.

Mine looks like this,

[image]

It shows the below window when i try to open the encrypted file,

[image]

And the output of `file /path/encryptedfile` shows the output like below,

```
$ file encp2
encp2: data
```

If it satisfies the above then try to open the file through truecrypt. But it requires password to unlock.

Comment: O.K, thanks all of you there, for your time but the question,How do I open Or fix this anomaly?..is yet to be answered.And let me clear  that I haven't encrypted by any encryption method. And below is a link to an article on Binary (application/octet-stream) file ,unfortunately it didn't help me. a)http://www.twobitcoder.com/?p=84 (b)https://kb.iu.edu/data/agtj.html

Comment: Just mount the file through truecrypt but it requires password. You can't open that file without a password.

Comment: I haven't installed True crypt, and I already made it clear that I did not encrypt my Hard disk. If you are saying that even if I didn't do the encryption I should do the mounting, how do you suppose I do that?

Comment: Someone may be created and copied it to your's.

Comment: Buddy, there's no way doing that.In my lab I and I alone sojourn.Is there any way I can open that wretched file?

Comment: Why don't you give a try to open it through truecrypt?